# Twilio - How to navigate users directly to flows edit page, if we have user credentials

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have Twilio credentails. When I listed flows, How can I directly navigate to flows edit screen? How to pass credentials along with this? I have account SID and Token.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? For what purpose would this be done? When you click to list the flows and click the flow, it takes you right to the respective Studio flow. That URL you see in the address bar is the direct link to the Studio Flow.

Comment: I have Twilio login id, password, account SID, token etc. I am able to fetch flow details using API calls. I am listing flows in our application. When I click one of the flows, I would like to show / navigate directly to flows edit screen. I can pass authorization details along with the request to navigate to flows. I could not find a solution for this in any of the documents.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The API and access to the Twilio Console are completely separate when it comes to authentication. There are no provisions in the API to create an authenticated link to the console, so I don't believe you can achieve this.

Instead, your users will have to log in to the Twilio console with their own credentials. If you have multiple users, they can sign up for their own Twilio accounts and you can add them to the requisite project, so you don't have to share your username and password.